# Eclipse error at the time of starting

Tags: eclipse, jboss, java-8, java-7, wildfly-11

I tried to move my project from java 7 to 8.when i start to debug my project via wildfly11 it is showing this error and my deployment gets failed.

```
 DEBUG [io.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JDK9 ALPN not supported: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava.lang.String;)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at io.undertow.protocols.alpn.JDK9AlpnProvider$1.run(JDK9AlpnProvider.java:47) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at io.undertow.protocols.alpn.JDK9AlpnProvider$1.run(JDK9AlpnProvider.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at io.undertow.protocols.alpn.JDK9AlpnProvider.<clinit>(JDK9AlpnProvider.java:43) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at io.undertow.protocols.alpn.ALPNManager.<init>(ALPNManager.java:40) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at io.undertow.protocols.alpn.ALPNManager.<clinit>(ALPNManager.java:35) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener.<init>(AlpnOpenListener.java:68) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener.<init>(AlpnOpenListener.java:90) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.AlpnOpenListener.<init>(AlpnOpenListener.java:82) [undertow-core-1.4.18.Final.jar:1.4.18.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.HttpsListenerService.createAlpnOpenListener(HttpsListenerService.java:101) [wildfly-undertow-11.0.0.Final.jar:11.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.HttpsListenerService.createOpenListener(HttpsListenerService.java:86) [wildfly-undertow-11.0.0.Final.jar:11.0.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:160) [wildfly-undertow-11.0.0.Final.jar:11.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1.jar:1.2.7.SP1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1.jar:1.2.7.SP1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of, there's no support for `Application Layer Protocol Negotiation(ALPN)` in both Java 7 or 8. There's no such method `setApplicationProtocols()` in the documentation of class `SSLParameters` for [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html) and [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html). I wonder how your project might be able to run in Java 7 without the `setApplicationProtocols()` method in the first place.

However, since Java 9, ALPN has become a part of the Java SE standard. You can find the documentation for `setApplicationProtocols()` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html).

If you do not want to upgrade to Java 9 and still use ALPN, you can go the Jetty project that provides a library with ALPN support. Jetty's ALPN boot jar works with both OpenJDK and Oracle's JDK (which is based on OpenJDK). There's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856972/http-2-java-8-jetty-and-alpn) on SO if you find any problem setting up the Jetty's ALPN jar.

Comment: @Sundar, if it solves your question, you should accept it as an answer. Welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error (and thus not using ALPN), set `enable-http2` of `http-listener` and `https-listener` to `false`